# Comment dire 発酵バター et 無発酵バター en français ? (beurre fermenté ou non)

Tags: traduction, terminologie, alimentation, japonais

Les termes japonais 発酵バター et 無発酵バター désignent respectivement le beurre *fermenté* ou *non fermenté*.

Ce n'est pas du beurre rance, c'est simplement une méthode de fabrication différente.

En fait, je ne sais même pas si 無発酵バター est vraiment appelé beurre en français...

Apparement 発酵バター est commun en Europe et 無発酵バター est commun aux USA et au Japon (ce n'est pas de la margarine, les deux sont vraiment fabriqués avec du lait).

*[Détails (en japonais)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC#.E7.A8.AE.E9.A1.9E)*

Comment: Je pense qu'une bonne source serait le *Larousse Gastronomique*…

Answer (score 6):

Je n'ai pas ma source principale sous la main (*[On Food and Cooking](http://www.amazon.fr/On-Food-And-Cooking-Science/dp/0684800012/ref=sr_1_1?s=english-books&ie=UTF8&qid=1340695943&sr=1-1)*, H. McGee) mais pour faire un résumé de la partie « alimentaire » de la question: le beurre peut être fait à partir de crème fermentée ou non. Dans le premier cas, on parlera en anglais de *fermented butter* ou *cultured butter*, tandis que le deuxième sera du *sweet cream butter* (ou du *raw cream butter* si la crème n'a pas été pasteurisée, ce qui est extrêmement rare de nos jours).

> Regular butter, or “sweet cream” butter, is the most common type found in North American grocery stores. It must be made from pasteurized milk and/or cream and must be at least 80% milk fat by weight, and should have a fresh, clean, slightly sweet flavour.
>
> Premium or "European style" butter (also called cultured or fermented), uses unpasteurized cream that is naturally fermented before made into butter. It claims to contain slightly more milk fat than regular butter, yet about the same amount of fat and calories, and usually costs about twice as much as other butters. It is more full-flavoured in taste, which is preferred throughout Europe. In North America, European-style butter is still made with pasteurized milk or cream, but a bacterial culture is introduced help mimic the slightly tangy, nutty flavour of the true European butter.

Pour la partie linguistique, on parle dans tous les cas de **beurre** en français. Simplement parce que le beurre qu'on achète en Europe est fermenté, tandis que le beurre qu'on achète sur le continent américain est non fermenté (les américains disent d'ailleurs parfois *European-style butter* pour le premier). Je n'ai jamais entendu faire explicitement la différence, mais lorsqu'on veut préciser, il semble qu'on dise **beurre fermenté** et [**beurre de crème douce**](http://azaquar.com/doc/technologie-de-fabrication-du-beurre), i.e. une traduction litérale de l'anglais.

Answer (score 1):

Il semblerait que la définition du  [beurre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beurre)

> Le beurre est obtenu en battant la crème tirée du lait. Pour obtenir un kilogramme de beurre, il faut environ 20 litres de lait entier. L’opération est souvent effectuée après maturation **(fermentation légère)** de la crème pendant 2 jours ce qui en développe l'arôme.

corresponde au *beurre fermenté*.

Le *fromage non fermenté* correspondrait alors à une [crème fraîche](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_fra%C3%AEche),  *épaisse* [et au lait entier] elle est proche de la consistance du beurre.

Ayant des goûts différents, on ne remplace pas l'un par l'autre dans les préparations culinaires.